# Python Curses - How would one space out multiple menu options horizontally?

Tags: python, python-3.x, curses, python-curses

I can easily print a list of menu options vertically in the terminal like so:

```
menu = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]

for idx, element in enumerate(menu):
    y = 1 + idx
    x = 1

    stdscr.addstr(y, x, element)
```

This outputs the following in my current set-up:

```
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
Option 4
```

But I am lost on how to do this horizontally. I've tried simply `x = 1 + idx` but that causes the output to be `OOOOption 4`, and I've tried a few variants. Does anyone have an idea of how I could achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do here is make a variable outside the loop which tells the `x, y`. Then in the x value has to be the `old x value`  + `len(element) + 1`.
So

```
menu = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]
y, x = 0, 0
for idx, element in enumerate(menu):
    stdscr.addstr(y, x, element)
    x = x + len(element) + 1
```

---

Hope i could help.